# A Simple stack language

Tags: haskell

I'm working through IOHK Haskell course from 2020, and I'm stuck on problem assignment W3.1, full description linked here:

https://github.com/iohkedu/w03

I do not understand how the `instructions` type is supposed to be ordered and evaluated. My code attempt introduces an extra parameter for initial stack, because otherwise I can't conceptualize how `IfZero` would be able to "look at the stack". Then my code attempt is

```
run :: Instructions -> [Int] -> Maybe [Int]  
run (Push n code) xs    = run code (n:xs) 
run (Pop code) (x:xs)   = run code xs
run (Add code) xs       = case xs of 
                            (x:y:ys) -> run code (x+y:ys)
                            otherwise -> Nothing
run (Mul code) xs       = case xs of 
                            (x:y:ys) -> run code (x*y:ys)    
                            otherwise -> Nothing    
run (Dup code) xs       = case xs of 
                            (x:ys) -> run code (x:x:ys)
                            otherwise -> Nothing
run (Swap code) xs      = case xs of  
                            (x:y:ys) -> run code (y:x:ys)
                            otherwise -> Nothing 
run (Over code) xs      = case xs of 
                            (x:y:ys) -> run code (y:x:y:ys)
                            otherwise -> Nothing 
run (Neg code) xs       = case xs of
                            (x:ys) -> run code (-x:ys)
                            otherwise -> Nothing 
run (IfZero c1 c2) xs   = case xs of 
                            (0:ys) -> run c1 xs 
                            (_:ys) -> run c2 xs 
                            otherwise -> Nothing    
run (Loop f) xs         = run (f (Loop f)) xs                                                                
run Halt xs             = Just xs
```

But when run on their example `fact5` instructions, my `run fact5 []` gives me the wrong output of `Just [0,0,1,4,9,16,25,1]`. I'm unable to even trace out on pen and paper what their `fact5` is supposed to be doing ...

```
fact5 :: Instructions
fact5 =
  Push 5 $
  Push 1 $
  Swap $
  Loop $ \ loop ->
  Dup $
  IfZero (Pop $ Halt) $
  Swap $
  Over $
  Mul $
  Swap $
  Push 1 $
  Neg $
  Add $
  loop
```

appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. My `IfElse` case was incorrect. It should be:

```
run (IfZero c1 c2) xs   = case xs of 
                            (0:ys) -> run c1 ys
                            (_:ys) -> run c2 ys 
                            otherwise -> Nothing
```